# What is lexicographical order?

Tags: string, sorting, terminology, lexicographic

What is the exact meaning of lexicographical order? How it is different from alphabetical order?

Answer (score 201, accepted):

lexicographical order **is** alphabetical order. The other type is numerical ordering. Consider the following values,

```
1, 10, 2
```

Those values are in lexicographical order.

in numerical order: 10 comes after 2,

but 10 comes before 2 in "alphabetical" - aka: lexicographical - order.

Comment: So in Lexicographical order, only the first digit will be considered of the value? Am I understanding right?

Comment: @NDesai No. If the first digits match, then the second digits will be compared; but it compares like a `String` - that is `10` comes before `2` but `111` comes after `10` (but also after `1000`). Because `0` is less than `1`. A lexical sort compares the characters in each string as characters, not integral values.

Comment: Hm. What about [C₂H₆](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethane) and [C₁₀H₂₂](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decane)?

Comment: @greybeard Wouldn't you want that in covalence order (it's been a while since a I had chemistry)?

Comment: `covalence order` (I didn't even find that in English wikipedia or literally using g°°gle - like (CH₃)₂ / CH₃(CH₂)₈CH₃ or even H₃C-CH₃? Four decades with me…) That was just the first example coming to mind with strings identical as far as letters are concerned, but with digit substrings where the order of numerical value is different from the order of the first digits.

Comment: "lexicographical order is alphabetical order". This isn't *quite* true. Ordering of tuples has been described as lexicographic even where no alphabet is involved, e.g., (0,4,2) is less than (1,3,2) according to a lexicographic comparison. See here for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_vector_space#Examples

Comment: The common alphabetical order is an example of a lexicographical order.

Answer (score 45):

**Alphabetical order** is a specific kind of **lexicographical ordering**. The term lexicographical often refers to the mathematical rules or sorting. These include, for example, proving logically that sorting is possible. Read more about lexicographical order on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order)

Alphabetical ordering includes variants that differ in how to handle spaces, uppercase characters, numerals, and punctuation. Purists believe that allowing characters other than a-z makes the sort not "alphabetic" and therefore it must fall in to the larger class of "lexicographic". Again, [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabetical_order) has additional details.

In computer programming, a related question is **dictionary order** or **ascii code** order. In dictionary order, the uppercase "A" sorts adjacent to lowercase "a". However, in many computer languages, the default string compare will use ascii codes. With ascii, all uppercase letters come before any lowercase letters, which means that that "Z" will sort before "a". This is sometimes called [ASCIIbetical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Character_order).

Answer (score 33):

This simply means "dictionary order", i.e., the way in which words are ordered in a dictionary. If you were to determine which one of the two words would come before the other in a dictionary, you would compare the words letter by the letter starting from the first position. For example, the word **"children"** will appear before (and can be considered smaller) than the word **"chill"** because the first four letters of the two words are the same but the letter at the fifth position in **"children"** (i.e. d ) comes before (or is smaller than) the letter at the fifth position in **"chill"** (i.e. l ). Observe that lengthwise, the word **"children"** is bigger than **"chill"** but length is not the criteria here. For the same reason, an array containing **12345** will appear
before an array containing **1235**. ([Deshmukh, OCP Java SE 11 Programmer I 1Z0815 Study guide 2019](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07VWMD2LB))

Comment: "This"? your first sentence is ambiguous when reading the full question.

Answer (score 11):

Lexicographical ordering means dictionary order.
For ex: In dictionary 'ado' comes after 'adieu' because 'o' comes after 'i' in English alphabetic system.
This ordering is not based on length of the string, but on the occurrence of the smallest letter first.

Answer (score 5):

I want to add an answer that is more related to the programming side of the term rather than the mathematical side of it.

Lexicographical order is not always an equivalent of "dictionary order", at least this definition is not complete in the realm of programming, rather, it refers to "**an ordering based on multiple criteria**".

For example, almost in all famous programming languages, there are standard tools for sorting collections of objects, now what if you want to sort a collection based on *more than one thing*? For instance, let's say you want to sort some items based on their prices first AND then based on their popularity. **This is an example of Lexicographical Order.**

For example in Java (8+), you could do something like this:

```java
// sorts items from the cheapest AND the most popular ones
// towards the most expensive AND the least popular ones.
Collections.sort(items,
    Comparator.comparing(Item::price)
   .thenComparing(Item::popularity)
   .reversed()
);
```

And the [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing-java.util.Comparator-) uses this term too, to refer to such type of ordering when explaining the "thenComapring()" method:

> Returns a **lexicographic-order** comparator with another comparator.

Answer (score 2):

Lexicographical order is nothing but the dictionary order or preferably the order in which words appear in the dictonary. For example, let's take three strings, "short", "shorthand" and "small". In the dictionary, "short" comes before "shorthand" and "shorthand" comes before "small". This is lexicographical order.

Comment: How is this different from the other answers that have been here for years? Perhaps you can find some unanswered questions that *need* an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something that can help understand better the **lexicographical ordering** with string is the following example.

Given the following Python script:

```py
words = ['apple', 'Banana', 'Cherry', 'Date', 'applepie']
max_word = max(words)
print(max_word)
```

The result will be surprisingly: 'applepie'

The motivation is that in the UNICAR sequence, the UPPERCASE LETTERs come before the LOWER CASE LETTERs.

To be more precise the UPPERCASE letters have a UNICHAR from **65 to 90 (A-Z)** and the LOWERCASE letters have a UNICHAR from **97 to 122 (a-z)**.
So by sorting the above list because 'applepie' have the **longest** string with **greater** UNICHAR characters, it has been returned by the max built-in function.