# Sort similar data by property

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following data:

```
[
  {
    DocumentId": "85",
    "figureText": "General Seat Assembly - DBL",
    "descriptionShort": "Seat Assembly - DBL",
    "partNumber": "1012626-001FG05",
    "itemNumeric": "5"
  },
  {
    DocumentId": "85",
    "figureText": "General Seat Assembly - DBL",
    "descriptionShort": "Seat Assembly - DBL",
    "partNumber": "1012626-001FG05",
    "itemNumeric": "45"
  }
]
```

I use the following query to get data:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "DocumentId": "85"
        }
      },
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "figureText": {
              "boost": 5,
              "query": "General Seat Assembly - DBL",
              "operator": "or"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "descriptionShort": {
              "boost": 4,
              "query": "Seat Assembly - DBL",
              "operator": "or"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "partNumber": {
              "boost": 1,
              "value": "1012626-001FG05"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Currently, it will returns the item with "itemNumeric" = 45 and I would like to get itemNumeric = "5" (the lowest).

Is a tips exists to do that ? I tried with "sort":[{"itemNumeric":"desc"}]

Thx

Comment: Try adding "sort": [{ "itemNumeric": "asc" }] or "sort": [{ "itemNumeric": { "order": "asc" }}]. If you want only the lowest you could specify "size": 1, to only get one result back (the lowest).

Comment: The query returns both the documents and its correct. Sort using "desc" and using size as "1", returns the document with itemNumeric 5. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I have this error when I try something "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [itemNumeric] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead.". I have a keyword field in my mapping ""itemGroup": {"type": "text", "fields": { "keyword": { "type": "keyword", "ignore_above": 256 } } }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your comment, you can resolve the issue in two ways.

**Solution 1:** Updating your mapping, so that your query would work as expected now

```
PUT my_index/_mapping/_doc
{
  "properties": {
    "itemNumeric": { 
      "type":     "text",
      "fielddata": true
    }
  }
}
```

**Solution 2:** Check the mapping of your `itemNumeric` field in case if your mapping has been created dynamically, you field itemNumeric would be multi-field.

```
"itemNumeric": {
    "type": "text",
     "fields": {
         "keyword": { 
             "type":  "keyword"
         }
     }
 }
```

In this case you can have your sorting logic applied on `itemNumeric.keyword` field.

```
"sort":[{"itemNumeric.keyword":"desc"}]
```

In elasticsearch, whenever you have text data, it is always recommended to have two fields created for it. One of type `text` so that you can apply full text queries and other of type `keyword` so that you can use if to implement sorting or any aggregation operations.

Solution 1 is not recommended as ES official documentation mentions below reason

> `Fielddata` is disabled on text fields by default. Set `fielddata=true` on
>   [your_field_name] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting
>   the inverted index. `Note that this can however use significant memory`.

I'd suggest to read about [multi-field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) and [fielddata](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html) so that you will have more clarity on what's happening.

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer, I use itemNumeric.keyword and it works but the `score` is defined to null now, is a solution exists to keep the score value with a sorting ?

Comment: You can just add `_score` to the sort logic. 
"sort": [{
     "desc.keyword": "asc"
  }, "_score"]

Comment: Yes it works, just a little another question (even if I know the answer), in the mapping, itemNumeric is a text value. If I sort by asc, 10 will come before 5 ? I have to update the mapping to integer to avoid that ?

Comment: Yes that's correct, sorting on string is lexicographical in nature which works differently than sorting on integer or long. Although there is a way to sort even text fields like this with numeric behaviour but its would require to make use of `painless` scripting which won't be efficient. Better strategy is to update your field to integer or long. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45950665/3838328