# Ordering of a string column that contains numbers in it using hive context

Tags: java, apache-spark, hivecontext

I have a column called priority among other columns in a file and contains numbers For ex: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 etc.
The file data is as follows

```
Department  Strength   Priority
--------------------------------
CS          Good       10
CS          Low        2
EC          Good       10
EC          Low        2
EC          Nil        3
```

I want to select the priority 2 records using a query using SQL hive context as below

```
select * from 
(
select testfile.*,row_number() over(partition by Department order by Priority asc) rn
from testfile
)ranked
where rn=1;
```

All the columns are defined as String in the spark code. I expect the code to select Priority 2 records because I have given the `asc` in `order by` clause. But is there a chance that the query selects priority other than 2 just because i didn't declare the priority column as int. Right now the query fetches the following data

```
 CS          Good       10
 EC          Good       10
```

However if I declare the Priority column as `int`, the records will be shown correctly as below

```
 CS          Low        2
 EC          Low        2
```

I would like to understand this. There are several instances where I declared the number column as string however got the ordering correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `order by` is using [lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order) which is similar to alphabetical order but alphabetical order is actually a type of lexicographical order.

It means that the following strings would be ordered as follows

```
1 < 2
10 < 2
1000 < 2
1 < 11
10 < 11 
21 < 3
```

In a simple way you could say it is ordering by each character position but you may read more from responses [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60604165/4307136) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order)

Furthermore, you may optionally cast your columns to integer to achieve numerical ordering for eg.

```sql
SELECT 
    *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        testfile.*,
        row_number() over(partition by Department order by cast(Priority as int) asc) rn
    FROM 
        testfile
) ranked
where rn=1;
```