# Persist the key in an object after Object.keys(),map() and sort()

Tags: javascript, dictionary, object, ecmascript-6

I got an object like this:

```
a = {
  CustomKey1: [
     {order: '2'},
     {order: '1'},
  ],
  CustomKey2: [
     {order: '2'},
     {order: '3'},
     {order: '1'},
  ],  
}
```

I need to sort based on the property "order" inside every object in every list.

I tried doing like this:

```
const result = Object.keys(a).map((customKey) => Object.keys(a[customKey]).map((key) => a[customKey][key]).sort((a, b) => a.order?.localeCompare(b.order)));
```

It works well, but in the result I lose the keys name, so I got:

```
total = {
  0: [
    {order: '1'},
    {order: '2'},
  ],
  1: [
    {order: '1'},
    {order: '2'},
    {order: '3'},
  ],
}
```

Is there a way to keep the original keys name? I need an object like this:

```
total = {
  CustomKey1: [
    {order: '1'},
    {order: '2'},
  ],
  CustomKey2: [
    {order: '1'},
    {order: '2'},
    {order: '3'},
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your object keys have to be unique.

You can iterate over the [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) with [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to build a new object.

```js
const a = {
  CustomKey1: [
     {order: '2'},
     {order: '1'},
  ],
  CustomKey2: [
     {order: '2'},
     {order: '3'},
     {order: '1'},
  ]
};

const result = Object.entries(a).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
  return {
    ...acc,
    [key]: value.sort((a, b) => a.order.localeCompare(b.order))
  };
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const a = {
  CustomKey1: [
     {order: '2'},
     {order: '1'},
  ],
  CustomKey2: [
     {order: '2'},
     {order: '3'},
     {order: '1'},
  ],  
};

const result = {};
for(const key in a){
  const values = a[key].slice(0);
  result[key] = values.sort((a, b) => a.order?.localeCompare(b.order));  
}

console.log("original", a);
console.log("sorted", result);
```

If the order values are guaranteed to be numeric, the sort should be changed to a numeric sort:

```
result[key] = values.sort((a, b) => Number(a.order) - Number(b.order));
```

This is because if you had an entry with `{ order: '10' }`, it currently will be sorted before `{ order: '2' }`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45950646/4282081) for more information.

Comment: Warning: This answer in it's current form will mutate the input object `a`.

Comment: Ah right, sort is in place. Good catch. I'll adjust my answer.

Comment: I also suggest making mention of why you changed the comparator function to use a numeric sort instead of a [lexicographic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45950646) sort.

Comment: Why'd you change it back to a lexicographic sort? The numeric sort was a valid bug fix.

Comment: There is no remark that guarantees that the order property will be numeric. If the question is adjusted to reflect that order values are stringified numbers, then I would revert to the previous solution.