# Sorting list of objects in python ( issues with sorted() )

Tags: python

I have a class called Veges:

```
class Veges: 
     def __init__(self,name,price):
          self.name=name
          self.price=price

     def getName(self):
          return str(self.name)

     def getPrice(self):
          return str("$") + str((self.price))
```

It can read a .txt file:

```
Cabbage,13.20
Bean sprouts,19.50
Celery,2.99
Zucchini,3.01
Eggplant,21.80
```

and create a list that contains my Veges objects:

```
for i in range( len ( textFile ) ):
        tmpArray = textFile[i].split(',')
        listOfVegetables.append(Veges(tmpArray[0],tmpArray[1]))
```

The problem comes when I use .sorted():

```
sorted_Vege = sorted(listOfVegetables, key=lambda x: x.getName())
```

While I can sort my vegetable objects by name:

```
Name: Bean sprouts 
Price: $19.50
Name: Cabbage 
Price: $13.20
Name: Celery 
Price: $2.99
Name: Eggplant 
Price: $21.80
Name: Zucchini 
Price: $3.01
```

I am unable to sort by price (I used x.getPrice()):

```
Name: Cabbage 
Price: $13.20
Name: Bean sprouts 
Price: $19.50
Name: Eggplant 
Price: $21.80
Name: Celery 
Price: $2.99
Name: Zucchini 
Price: $3.01
```

I noticed that the double-digit Veges are sorted correctly but the single-digit Veges (Celery & Zucchini) are sorted separately.

How do I fix this?

Just in case, here is how I print my sorted list of objects:

```
def printVeges(listOfVegetables,index):
    print("Name:", listOfVegetables[index].getName())
    print("Price:", listOfVegetables[index].getPrice())

for i in range(len(sorted_Mov)):
    printVeges(sorted_Vege,i)
```

Comment: If you use `x.price` as the key instead it will be using the number to compare. Using value from `x.getPrice()` which is string, it will be sorted lexicographically see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45950646/what-is-lexicographical-order

Comment: Your `getPrice()` returns string thats y

Comment: In string comparison “$20” is less than “$3” because “2” is less than “3”. You should compare these prices as numbers not strings, or 0-fill the price string so you’re comparing “$03” with “$20”

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort a list of strings numerically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426108/how-to-sort-a-list-of-strings-numerically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sorting based on the string. A workaround can be to convert the string to float and sort based on that. Please check this out:

```
sorted(listOfVegetables, key=lambda x: float(x.getPrice()[1:]))
```

`x.getPrice()[1:]` will get rid of `$` and will give digits only.