# Having problem comparing integer type number with string type number using $lt operator

Tags: php, mongodb

I am having a problem trying to execute a simple find method using `$lt`.  i.e. Fetch rows where `Id` is less than 5. Simple

Below is my query:

```
$result = $collection->find($data);
```

Where `$data` is:

```
[id] => Array
        (
            [$lt] => 5
        )
```

But as a result, I am getting the `Id`, But it compares only the first digit.
Returning Ids are:

```
[{"_id":{"$oid":"615839a18ffb730a922af032"},"id":"1"},
{"_id":{"$oid":"615839a18ffb730a922af033"},"id":"2"},
{"_id":{"$oid":"615839a18ffb730a922af039"},"id":"15"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"615839a18ffb730a922af039"},"id":"45"}
```

Why it is comparing only First Digit of `Id`. Why `$lt` not working on the whole `Id`?

I am getting Ids 1,2,14,45,466 etc. All the first digit starts less than 5. But want the result less than 5 instead of the First digit.

Comment: Why do you store numeric values as strings? Store numbers (integer or double or long) then the query will work.

Comment: I suspect the `5` in your query is actually a string, and MongoDB is using [lexicographical ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45950646/what-is-lexicographical-order) to compare the values.  Try using `var_dump` instead of `print_r` to examine the value of `$data`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, its a client database. Not under my control. I have use it like the way it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why it is comparing only First Digit of `Id`. Why `$lt` not working on the whole `Id`?

Because `id` has string type numbers, and you are searching for integer type numbers.

You can use [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) operator and aggregation expression syntax of [$lt](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/operator/aggregation/lt/) operator, and `$toInt` to convert `id` field's value to integer,

```
$data = [
  '$expr' => [
    '$lt' => [
      ['$toInt' => '$id'],
      5
    ]
  ]
]
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CCLRjH_x4J8)

Comment: I am getting error unknown operator: $expr

Comment: what is the version of your mongodb server?

Comment: you can use aggregation query, but the `$toInt` will not work because it is started from v4, so i would suggest you to upgrade your mongodb to latest version of store that value in number instead of string.

Comment: so there is only option you can upgrade mongodb version.

Comment: You can use $and operator to merge both the conditions [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/98AqxXtHL8B)