# Limit to last message Firebase realtime database. React Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to get the last message in my Firebase Realtime Database given the value of a child inside the message. Is this possible?

Here is my messages below in the realtime database:

[image]

[image]

I would like to obtain the last message which was sent with 'sentWhileBlocked' == false. Can this be achieved using the firebase realtime database query? What will be the query if so?

This is the query I have so far which prints the last message:

```
 db.ref('messages').child(childSnapshot.key).orderByKey().limitToLast(1).on('value', (dataSnapshots) => {
    if (dataSnapshots.val()) {
       console.log("val key: "+JSON.stringify(dataSnapshots.val()));
    }
 });
```

Would I need to do this with a for loop? If so, how would this look?

Thanks.

Comment: Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property. In many cases it is possible to combine the values you want to filter on into a single (synthetic) property. In your case that could be `"sentWhileBlocked_timestamp": "false_1634376119733"`. For a longer example of this and other approaches, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Answer (score 1):

In comparison to Cloud Firestore, the Firebase Realtime Database has very limited built-in query functionality. One of these limitations is that RTDB queries can only be performed on a single child value - there is no `name1=value1 AND name2=value2` query functionality.

From here, you have two options if you chose to stick with the RTDB as your database:

#### Option 1) Rely on the order of the message keys

When using `orderByChild` to [sort data in a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#orderbychild), duplicates are [sorted lexicographically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45950646/3068190) by key.

This means your query can be as simple as:

```js
const query = db.ref('messages')
  .child(childSnapshot.key)
  .orderByChild("sentWhileBlocked")
  .equalTo(false)
  .limitToLast(1);

query
  .then((querySnapshot) => {
    if (!querySnapshot.hasChildren()) {
      // handle no sentWhileBlocked=false values
      console.error(`No matching messages found.`);
    } else {
      let messageSnapshot;
      querySnapshot.forEach(s => messageSnapshot = s);
      // do something with messageSnapshot
      console.log(`Matching Message ID: ${messageSnapshot.key}`);
    }
  })
  .catch((err) => { ... })
```

#### Option 2) Denormalize your data to create a composite index

While you can rely on the order of keys to sort your data, as you store a timestamp value, you can use that value to sort the data instead. This may be important if you update the timestamp value when a user edits their message. While you could loop through your structure as you came up with to find the latest timestamp with a `sentWhileBlocked` value of `false`, this is inefficient at scale as you could end up downloading a whole bunch of unnecessary data. What you will need to do is "denormalize" your data by creating an index that merges both your `timestamp` and `sentWhileBlocked` fields. This [Firebase video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sKFLI5FOOHs) covers it as query #8.

When merging the two fields, you may be tempted to toggle a binary bit or throw a `1` or `0` at the start of the timestamp to store the `sentWhileBlocked` value. This introduces an issue where some clients may treat this as a number larger than what a 32bit signed integer can handle which could lead to overflow problems.

To force Firebase to not treat it as numeric, concatenate the values with a symbol that doesn't occur in a valid number:

```json
{
  sentWhileBlocked: false,
  timestamp: 1634376119733,
  sentWhileBlocked_timestamp: "0_1634376119733", // or "false_1634376119733"
  // ...
}
```

In its current form this introduces a new problem - this value is now [lexicographically sorted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45950646/3068190) because it is now a string, not a number. As an example, if you had the array `["1","2","3","10","11"]` and you sort it, you end up with `["1","10","11","2","3"]`. To prevent this causing problems, we should make sure to pad this number with at least 1 zero so that when the timestamp passes 10000000000 (in 2086), your timestamps don't screw up.

This gives a new structure of:

```json
{
  sentWhileBlocked: false,
  timestamp: 1634376119733,
  sentWhileBlocked_timestamp: "0_01634376119733",
  // ...
}
```

When writing that data to the database, you can merge the values and pad the number value of `timestamp` as needed using:

```
const newMessageData = {
  sentWhileBlocked: false,
  timestamp: 1634376119733,
  // ...
}

// before writing to RTDB
newMessageData.sentWhileBlocked_timestamp = (messageData.sentWhileBlocked ? "1" : "0") + "_" + messageData.timestamp.toString().padStart(14,"0");

// write newMessageData to database
db.ref("messages")
  .child(chatroomId)
  .push(newMessageData)
  .then(() => console.log("Uploaded message"))
  .catch((err) => console.error("Failed to upload message", err))
```

This allows you to use this query to fetch the latest message with `sentWhileBlocked` set to `false`:

```js
const query = db.ref('messages')
  .child(childSnapshot.key)
  .orderByChild("sentWhileBlocked_timestamp")
  .endsWith("0_\uf8ff") // use .startsWith("1_") for `sentWhileBlocked` = `true`
  .limitToLast(1);

query
  .then((querySnapshot) => {
    if (!querySnapshot.hasChildren()) {
      // handle no sentWhileBlocked=false values
      console.error(`No matching messages found.`);
    } else {
      let messageSnapshot;
      querySnapshot.forEach(s => messageSnapshot = s);
      // do something with messageSnapshot
      console.log(`Matching Message ID: ${messageSnapshot.key}`);
    }
  })
  .catch((err) => { ... })
```

Note: If using this method, you should [add this field to your ".indexOn" list](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data) in your Firebase RTDB Security Rules for the best performance.