# How to use the smaller as operater on strings?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I saw a lot of this kind of SQL statements. The are a WHERE condition with < as on a string column. But how is this possible? A string ist not a number.

```
SELECT 
       [SalesTerritoryCountry]
      ,[SalesTerritoryGroup]
  FROM [AdventureWorksDW2019].[dbo].[DimSalesTerritory]
WHERE [SalesTerritoryCountry] < [SalesTerritoryGroup]
```

Comment: It's called lexicographical ordering. Strings are compared character-wise, from the first character.

Comment: This ^. Read more about it here: [What is lexicographical order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45950646/what-is-lexicographical-order)