# Less than is not working properly in bash if the value is 10.00

Tags: bash, if-statement

We are getting an unexpected output while running the following codes

```
PYLINT_SCORE=10.00
THRESHOLD=7

if [[ $PYLINT_SCORE < $THRESHOLD ]]; then
    echo "Your Code is not meet the threashold value";
else
    echo "Your Code meet the threashold value";
 fi;
```

Here we are getting "**Your Code is not meet the threashold value**"

But if run the following code we are getting the correct output like "**Your Code meet the threashold value**"

```
PYLINT_SCORE=9.99
THRESHOLD=7

if [[ $PYLINT_SCORE < $THRESHOLD ]]; then
    echo "Your Code is not meet the threashold value";
else
    echo "Your Code meet the threashold value";
 fi;
```

Comment: `bash` can only handle integers.

Comment: the `<` and `>` sorts in [lexicographical-order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45950646/what-is-lexicographical-order)