# How to check if a number is outside a dynamic range in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, variables

I have a pizza builder code. It gives the user to chose a pizza size and a list of toppings from a side file.
I'm trying to validate users input so it can enter a number between *1* and the *amount of toppings* from the side file.

I'm getting the number of rows from the file and set it to a variable using wc
`numtop=$( cat Toppings | wc -l );`

After that I read the users input and run a check using if

```
read topp
if [[ "$topp" < 1 || "$topp" > "$numtop" ]]; then
     echo "Enter from 1 to " $numtop
else
     echo "Good choice"
fi
```

But it allows me to enter only 1 or the number from my $numtop variable. I can't understand why this doesn't work.

Comment: `<` and `>` compare strings. use `-gt` or `-lt` for numbers

Comment: and do a test for non-digits before checking the value is in range

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `(( ))` for [arithmetic](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html) expression, something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

numtop="$(wc -l < Toppings)"

while read -rp "Enter from 1 to  $numtop " topp; do
  if (( topp < 1 || topp > numtop )); then
    echo "Enter from 1 to $numtop"
  else
    echo "Good choice"
    break
  fi
done
```

---

EDIT: as per `@jhnc`, Given the input is something like: `a[$(date>/dev/tty)],1` (the first answer breaks badly) check the value of input first if it is strictly numeric.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

##: Test also if Toppings is empty if it is a file
##: or just test the value of $numtop.
numtop="$(wc -l < Toppings)"

while printf 'Enter from 1 to %s ' "$numtop"; do
  read -r topp
  case $topp in
    ('')
      printf 'input is empty\n' >&2
       ;;
    (*[!0123456789]*)
       printf '%s has a non-digit somewhere in it\n' "$topp" >&2
       ;;
    (*)
      if (( topp < 1 || topp > numtop )); then
        printf 'You entered %s\n' "$topp"  >&2
      else
        printf 'You entered %s Good choice!\n' "$topp" &&
        break
      fi
     ;;
  esac
done
```

---

- The `<` and `>` when used in `[[ ... ]]` is not for [arithmetic expression](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html) in bash, see `help test`. It is used for testing strings [lexicographical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45950646/what-is-lexicographical-order)
- See [Conditional Constructs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html) from the online bash manual and look for the `[[ expression ]]`, which states: `When used with [[, the ‘<’ and ‘>’ operators sort lexicographically using the current locale.`
- See [How can I tell whether a variable contains a valid number?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/054).
- `numtop=$( cat Toppings | wc -l );` is a form of [UUOC](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/119)

Comment: you should check for non-digits first. consider if user enters: `a[$(date>/dev/tty)],1`